# GridView with images from XAMPP server

Tags: android, xml, gridview, xampp, gallery

I have to do android app which includes Gallery with GridView and images should be from a XAMPP server ,not from a folder(drawable) like this:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

public static int[] images = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6,
                R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8,
                R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10,
                R.drawable.image11, R.drawable.image12,
                R.drawable.image13, R.drawable.image14};
private Context context;

public ImageAdapter (Context applicationContext)
{
    context = applicationContext;
}
```

And the images should be clickable (zoom).Thanks :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: https://github.com/palmerc/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

This code fulfills both your requirements.

The original code comes from Nostra13, but if I remember correctly, from a previous stackoverflow post, this guy Palmerc corrected a thing or two from it.